# Pandas df to database using flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert a pandas dataframe into a mysql database. I am using flask-sqlalchemy.

I have created this table:

```
class Client_Details(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "client_history"

    client_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_name = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(50))
    shack= db.Column(db.VARCHAR(50))
```

and I would like to insert the data from this df into it:

```
index   name     shack
0        jay       H9
1        ray       I8
2        t-bop     I6
3        jay-k     F89
4        phil      D89
```

This doesn't seem to work:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    client_add = client_history(client_name = row[1], shack =row[2])
    db.session.add(client_add)
    db.session.commit()
```

Is there a better way to do this, using `to_sql`, perhaps?

Comment: `df.to_sql()` will do the trick, although I find it to be very slow for large tables.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kyle's answer was close - the flask-sqlalchemy engine IS created behind the scenes with some magic, but the correct way to access it is with db.engine. Here's what you're looking for:

```
df.to_sql(name='client_history', con=db.engine, index=False)
```

I also agree with VinceP's assessment that to_sql can be slow for larger tables, so keep that in mind.

For what it's worth, you can also access the session with Flask-SQLAlchemy as db.session.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.to_sql(engine, 'client_history')
```

Is what you are looking for.  There is no lighting fast way to do this (that I am aware of) but typically using builtin pandas functions is going to be faster than any solution that you can create on your own.

Comment: thanks. sqlalchemy doesn't use the `engine`, how does one do this with flask?`app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

db = SQLAlchemy(app)`

Comment: SQLAlchemy does use the `engine`.  I am not 100% sure about how to get the engine with sqlalchemy + flask but I would guess that you can access it through your `db` object if that is not an instance of the `engine` already.